# Prove $\frac{1+ab}{\sqrt{1+a^2}\times\sqrt{1+b^2}} > 0.5 $

Tags: geometry

Prove $$\frac{1+ab}{\sqrt{1+a^2}\times\sqrt{1+b^2}} > 0.5 $$ for $a, b>0$ reals.

I have tried by rearranging to

$${1+ab} > 0.5 \times {\sqrt{1+a^2}\times\sqrt{1+b^2}}$$

and I am thinking that if I draw a line segment AB of length a, continuing to C of length b, then set a perpendicular segment in B of length 1 to D then the area of the ADC triangle is almost the right hand side except there's a $\sin ACD$ to it ... And/or somethig similar to the classic Pythagorean proof http://faculty.smcm.edu/sgoldstine/pyth.gif ... I feel like I am close but I can't quite finish it.

Comment: In the title, it should be $0.5$?

Comment: +1 for suggesting a geometric approach to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

WLOG let $a=\tan A, b=\tan B$ with $0<A,B<90^\circ$

$$\dfrac{1+\tan A\tan B}{\sec A\sec B}=\cos(A-B)$$

What if $A-B\ge60^\circ$  say $A=80^\circ, B=\cdots$

Comment: So you are saying this is not always true only for specific a and b? Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong! Try $b=\frac{1}{3}$ and $a\rightarrow+\infty$.